# Generating all size-k consecutive subsets in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am interested in splitting any list into consecutive subsets based on a k-value.  For example, `[1,2,3,4,5]` splits into `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]` when `k=2`.  If k is bigger than the entire list, then an empty list will be returned.

I am unhappy with my current solution and would like to have suggestions on how to improve it.  Specifically I would like to be able to code a more terse solution.  I find that terseness in functional programming languages, such as Haskell, is important to keep in mind.  I feel that there is a way of expressing my Haskell solution using a fold possibly, but I just cannot see how at this moment.

```
consSizeK :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
consSizeK _ [] = []
consSizeK k list@(_:tail)
    | k > length list = []
    | otherwise = (take k list) : consSizeK k tail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each evaluation of `length list` will take time proportional to the length of the list, which will slow this down.

We know that there will be `length xs - n + 1` sublists of `xs` of length `n`. We can use this to make the code much faster.

```
sublists n xs = take (length xs - n + 1) $ sublists' n xs
    where sublists' _ [] = [[]]
          sublists' n xs@(_:rest) = take n xs : sublists' n rest
```

For comparison, with

```
main = print $ sum $ map length $ sublists 2 [1 .. 100000]
```

I get the following timings on my machine, compiled with `-O`.

Original version:

```
$ time ./orig
199998

real    0m14.890s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
```

This version:

```
$ time ./new
199998

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: @KevinTindall I realised there's a simpler solution, will update the post soon.

Comment: What could be more simple than SimpleQueue? lol

Comment: @KevinTindall lol well hopefully this version is. I've updated the timings as well since I'm running on a different machine and OS.